# How to write rules that skip the job when any of the specified files doesn't exist?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Here I have rules for a job so that it's added to the pipeline if and only if `do_job` is set and `skip_job` is not set.

```yaml
rules:
- if: $skip_job == "true"
  when: never
- if: $do_job != "false"
```

How to add a rule that also skips the job when any of the two files is missing?

(the two files are `tasks.yml` and `inputs.yml`)

Something like that:

```yaml
rules:
- if: $skip_job == "true"
  when: never
- does_not_exist:
  - tasks.yml
  when: never
- does_not_exist:
  - inputs.yml
  when: never
- if: $do_job != "false"
```

Comment: you could write an if condition to test for file like `- if: -z tasks.yml`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle no, you can't. There is no shell interpreter there to do such a thing there.

Comment: Doh thanks @velkin was totally in shell mode. What about combining the if with and exists so inly turn the job if the flag is set and both files exist

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/244932 This issue is not yet closed, so I assume you need a workaround

Comment: You could check for the files in the before_script section and set environment variable accordingly